# Creating Aggregation and Composition in class diagram in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, uml

I am thinking about creating a class diagram in Visual Studio. I notice that the Toolbox only appears to allow Association relationships between classes.

Is it possible to create stronger relationships in the class diagram, i.e. Aggregation and Composition relationships?

Also, is it possible to automatically create the class diagram from the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great Question.

**First of all**: Visual Studio (VS) Class Designer is not a [**CASE Tools**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_software_engineering) (like Enterprise Architect and etc.). 
It is only a class representation of the source codes. Meaning that classes in class designer are always synchronized with the classes in the source code. If you delete some attributes or methods in source code, it synchronized with class designer and vise versa.

**Secondly**: The answer of this question hides in mapping Association and Aggregation (and Composition) to source code.

To map Associations, Aggregation and Composition to source code see: [Reference 1](https://dzone.com/articles/uml2-class-diagram-java) and [Reference 2](https://www1.in.tum.de/lehrstuhl_1/files/teaching/ss07/SE/SE2007_Lecture16.pdf).

**Detecting Association or Aggregation or Composition relationships between classes from the Source Code is impossible in some cases.**

For example, what type of relationship is between `Customer` and `Car` in below code?

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String contactNumber;

    private Car car;        
}


public class Car {
    private String modelNumber;
    private Customer owner;
}
```

It can be Association or Aggregation.

**Finally**, because of first and second reasons as described above, Visual Studio Class Diagram do not have Aggregation and Composition.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the reference to CASE tools.

Comment: I have an interface and a class.  The class implements all of the methods from the interface.  How do I add a link between the class and the interface?

Comment: Also, say I have a class that contains an IEnumerable<Order>.  On the class diagram there is a link between the class and the IEnumerable<Order>.  How do I add a link between IEnumerable<Order> and Order?

Comment: @w0051977, Thanks, that is **Realization** relationship in UML between an Interface and a Class. **Note that** any class that implements an interface, SHOULD implements all methods of interface.

Comment: How do I add the Realization relationship on the class diagram? I have already written the code.

Comment: You second question (Relationship between  `IEnumerable<Order>` and `Order`) is very good question. please see [this reference](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/uml2/docs/articles/Defining_Generics_with_UML_Templates/article.html)

Comment: Which Tools are you using? Visual Studio Class Designer??

Comment: To add Realization see [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409416.aspx) It's so complete guidelines

Comment: Yes, I am using Visual Studio Class Designer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161653/discussion-between-gholamali-irani-and-w0051977).

Comment: Please have a look at my other question here if you get chance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923225/showing-the-weakest-form-of-association-on-a-visual-studio-class-diagram

Comment: @Gholamali-Irani **"Realization relationship in UML between an Interface and a Class."** How do you think the relationship between `template <typename T> class Foo{}` and `Foo<int>`?