# Showing the Dependency Relationship on a Visual Studio class diagram

Tags: visual-studio, uml

Say I have a class structure like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
}

public class Bar
{
    public void Test(IFoo foo)
}
```

Is it possible to show an association relationship between `Foo` and `Bar` (the weakest relationship).  Should I even be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Thomas Kilian said your relationship (between `Bar` and `IFoo`) is **not** any types of Association. It can be **Dependency relationship**.

To have more explaination about **Dependency Relationship**: 
Dependency Relationship is one of UML relationships and it stand on top of other type dependencies.

[image]

Your dependency is type of Usage: **use Dependency**. (see [reference 1](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-core-reference.html))

> For example, it could mean that some method(s) within a (client) class
>   uses objects (e.g. parameters) of the another (supplier) class.

**Unfortunately**, Class Designer of Visual Studio, **ONLY** shows Inheritance and Association.

**If we want to explain the idea:** 
Dependency Relationship did not show **remarkable** things between classes. There are many types of Dependencies (see [reference 1](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-core-reference.html) and [reference 2](https://cppcodetips.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/uml-class-diagram-explained-with-c-samples/)) and if Class Designer wants to show each type of relationship, our diagrams will be so **messy**.

**In the other hand**, Dependency Relationship mostly use in Requirement and Analysis phase of Methodologies. (not mostly in implementation)

**For this reason**, if you reverse engineer your code to have Class Diagram of your code in [CASE Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_software_engineering) (like Enterprise Architect), the dependency relationship **will not draw** by the CASE Tools.

Answer (score 1):

You will show a dependency, which is the weakest form. And you draw it to the interface like this:

[image]

Comment: How do I do this in Visual Studio? There is no component called: Dependency in the Class Designer toolbox.  Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea about VS, but it's not a UML case tool. It just has some "adornment" that looks like UML. The above is how it should look like in UML.