# specifying containment kind of relation for owl class and objectProperty

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, owl-api

I come from UML world and now I am trying to see if in ontology I can **specify containment relationship between owl class and objectProperty**.

Will be helpful if any of you can let me know how to define such relation in OWL RDF/XML.

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Do you mean UML composition?

Comment: yes true. I am looking if there is a way to establish such scenario with containment between objectproperty and owl class. so that at instance level it is ensured that i can associate a instance of property inside only one individual

Comment: Hrm, could you draw an UML diagram?

Comment: See my answer for SO question [UML class diagram: Association or Composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286294/uml-class-diagram-association-or-composition/48287838#48287838). Due to composition (and aggregation) being poorly specified in UML, it cannot be represented in OWL/RDF.

Comment: ok. thanks for the info