# Composition and Aggregation referencing the same class (UML / TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, uml

Is it possible and does it make sense that Hero has an aggregation and composition relationship?

My aim is to keep a list of powers for each hero, however when creating one it should only be possible to add one Power instead of multiple Powers. That is the reason why I've created a private attribute power for only one power.

My question is about the validity of the UML class diagram. Is that the correct way of displaying my intend?

The reason why power is an aggregation is that it could be that another class uses the same power instance (I have implemented some cache which always return the same instance of a power, for simplicity I didn't show that part).

The reason why powers is an composition is that it strongly depends on the hero instance. If hero is destroyed, powers should also be cleaned.

[image: Hero UML Composition, Aggregation]

The code for the UML does look like something like that (TypeScript):

hero.ts

```
import { Power } from './power';

export class Hero {
  powers: Power[] = [];

  constructor(private power?: Power) {
    if (power) {
      this.addPower(power);
    }
  }

  addPower(power: Power) {
    this.powers.push(power);
  }

}
```

power.ts

```
export class Power {
  constructor(private title: string) { }
}
```

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268986/is-correct-relatshass-digram-crrel though the OP there is trolling at the moment :-/

Comment: Your list of Power is it fixed for all Heros or each Hero will have acces to a different set of Power?

Comment: Hi, @1 so you say that I should better use association with multiplicities instead of aggregation and composition? 

@2 each Hero should have a different set of Powers

Comment: Yes, multiplicity is in almost all cases the better choice. And it saves a lot of headaches.

Comment: Rather than editing your question with the answer you should post that as a new "answer to self". That would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all**: it is possible to have an Aggregation and Composition between two classes. As you said correctly, if our `part class` should be deleted with `whole class`, we should use Composition, and if not, we can use Aggregation (or Association). It is possible to have both in one direction (as you have, only the recursive relation is not possible)

Based on you explanation:

> My aim is to keep a list of powers for each hero, however **when**
>   **creating** one it should only be possible to add one Power instead of
>   multiple Powers. That is the reason why i've created a private
>   attribute power for only one power.

You **do not** have Aggregation between `Hero` and `Power`. That is only 
 a **Dependency** relationship between them. Based on your codes and explanation, you do not save the **ONE power** in your codes and only it used for setting instances to `POWERS` in `Hero`. Meaning that your `Hero` has not any single `Power` as `part class`.

**However**, your Composition between them is absolutely correct. Because you said:

> it strongly depends on the hero instance. If hero is destroyed, powers
>   should also be cleaned.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed answer. I think I have an Aggregation because I save one power at the initialization of one instance. If the constructor in typescript contains something with a modifier and a type, typescript will initialize the value. E.g. writing constructor(private power: Power) resolves to this: 

export class Hero {
  powers: Power[] = [];
  power: Power;

  constructor(power?: Power) {
    if (power) {
      this.power = power;
      this.addPower(power);
    }
  }

or is it something else that you mean?

Comment: I think, the `power` that generated at initialization, is something like a temporary variable to handle your codes. We use Aggregation because of Structural reasons.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution** based on accepted answer in UML:
[image]

In TypeScript it's better to not instantiate a attribut of type Power because it has no further purpose. Therefore the constructor just get a Power and is adding it to the powers array.

hero.ts

```
import { Power } from './power';

export class Hero {
  powers: Power[] = [];

  constructor(power?: Power) {
    if (power) {
      this.addPower(power);
    }
  }

  addPower(power: Power) {
    this.powers.push(power);
  }

}
```

Comment: I think the `<<use>>` is just superfluous. The association already implies that you use `Power`.